# FLUTTER How do I get rid of "FATAL EXCEPTION: ScreenDecorations"?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

I'm having a Problem with Android Studio. I updated it recently to Dolphin and since then I can't start my apps on the emulator.
I already tried a few things and my last was to delete everything (Android Studio, SDKs, Git) and install it again. I also tried `flutter doctor` but it shows no errors.

I'm getting following output from the console which is repeated till i stop the program:

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
E/AndroidRuntime(31480): FATAL EXCEPTION: ScreenDecorations
E/AndroidRuntime(31480): Process: com.android.systemui, PID: 31480
E/AndroidRuntime(31480): java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter, parameter bottomLeft
E/AndroidRuntime(31480):    at com.android.systemui.statusbar.events.PrivacyDotViewController.initialize(Unknown Source:22)
E/AndroidRuntime(31480):    at com.android.systemui.ScreenDecorations.setupDecorations(ScreenDecorations.java:315)
E/AndroidRuntime(31480):    at com.android.systemui.ScreenDecorations.startOnScreenDecorationsThread(ScreenDecorations.java:252)
E/AndroidRuntime(31480):    at com.android.systemui.ScreenDecorations.$r8$lambda$bRx4s-frKyGv-SmpobluoualBbQ(Unknown Source:0)
E/AndroidRuntime(31480):    at com.android.systemui.ScreenDecorations$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.run(Unknown Source:2)
E/AndroidRuntime(31480):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
E/AndroidRuntime(31480):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(31480):    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
E/AndroidRuntime(31480):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
E/AndroidRuntime(31480):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

Comment: Did you try to remove your ~/.gradle folder?

Comment: Does it happen with every project? What if you start a new project?

Comment: @kingston I tried it but it didn't change the console output.

Comment: @Ivo Yes the example is from a new standard flutter project

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I experience the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I deleted everything that had to do with Android Studio on my disk (i searched manually for every little file). Then I reinstalled android studio. I also created a new Virtual Device with the AVD for my emulator and added more RAM through the Advanced Settings it finally worked. Unfortunately I don't know what caused the problem exactly.

Comment: I experience the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was facing the same issue. I think it is a known issue in android emulator due to pinhole cutout ([chick here for more details](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/243189303)). I switched to a device without pin hole camera and the issue was resolved.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33170672)

Comment: I now believe too that the emulator was the reason for my issue

Comment: I had this issue with the Pixel 6 emulator (center camera) but not with Pixel 5 (left-side camera).

Comment: So does this mean we can't test on any phones greater than Android 5??

Comment: No @Badrul you can use any android version you want. Its just that the emulator skin should not have pinhole cutout.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was struggling for 2 days. Finally found your answer

Answer (score 0):

Solved with Android API 33 (Android Tiramisu). Installing the same emulator (i.e. my case Pixel 6) with API 33 that problem disappear.