# Fatal Screen Decorations Exception on Initial Flutter Run

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

I am trying to get started building an app with Flutter. I've just followed the installation and setup steps in the documentation.  I've written the basic structure of an app:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(TestApp());
}

class TestApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestApp({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

but when I try to `flutter run`, I get the following exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(11263): FATAL EXCEPTION: ScreenDecorations
E/AndroidRuntime(11263): Process: com.android.systemui, PID: 11263
E/AndroidRuntime(11263): java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter, parameter bottomLeft
E/AndroidRuntime(11263):        at com.android.systemui.statusbar.events.PrivacyDotViewController.initialize(Unknown Source:22)
E/AndroidRuntime(11263):        at com.android.systemui.ScreenDecorations.setupDecorations(ScreenDecorations.java:315)
E/AndroidRuntime(11263):        at com.android.systemui.ScreenDecorations.startOnScreenDecorationsThread(ScreenDecorations.java:252)
E/AndroidRuntime(11263):        at com.android.systemui.ScreenDecorations.$r8$lambda$bRx4s-frKyGv-SmpobluoualBbQ(Unknown Source:0)
E/AndroidRuntime(11263):        at com.android.systemui.ScreenDecorations$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.run(Unknown Source:2)
E/AndroidRuntime(11263):        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
E/AndroidRuntime(11263):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(11263):        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
E/AndroidRuntime(11263):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
E/AndroidRuntime(11263):        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I'm using Android Studio with Flutter and Dart plugins, the built-in JDK 17, and Gradle 8.0 with a Pixel 6 emulator.

I've tried the following:

- Making sure the Java, Android plugin, and Gradle versions are compatible
- Changing the `JAVA_HOME` variable to the Android Studio JRE

Comment: The error you are experiencing seems to be related to the system UI, not your Flutter code. It's possible that there is an issue with the emulator or the device you are running the app on.

Comment: @techStud Yes, it turns out that's exactly what it was! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

After doing some research, it turns out this is a known issue for emulators with a pinhole cutout, like the Pixel 6 I was using, which has a center pinhole camera (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73960094/21818946)).  After switching to the Pixel 5 emulator (interestingly, which has a pinhole camera on the left side), this seems to have fixed the issue.